# Flutter textfield that auto expands when text is entered and then starts scrolling the text when a certain height is reached

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield

I've tried many configurations of the Flutter TextField but can't figure out how to build this one.

I'm looking for a textfield that is a single line initially and it auto expands as the text is entered into it and then at some point begins scrolling itself.

This can be achieved partially by using the maxLines: null attribute. But then when a lot of text is entered the Text in the textfield itself overflows.

And if the maxLines is set to a value then the whole textfield itself gets expanded to those many lines to start off with rather than beginning with a single line.

Is there a way to limit the height of textfield at some point like done in many chat apps like WhatsApp and telegram.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```dart
Container(
    child: new ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 300.0,
        ),
        child: TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

In older Flutter versions it was

```dart
Container(
    child: new ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 300.0,
        ),
        child: new Scrollbar(
            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                reverse: true,
                child: new TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I think this answer should be edited to refer to the new way of using minLines and maxLines as proposed by @flomaster.

Answer (score 49):

Now we actually have `minLines` parameter of `TextField`, no workaround needed anymore.

```
TextField(
    minLines: 1,
    maxLines: 5,
)
```

Comment: this should be accepted answer works well in all situations even if the direct child of the constrained box is not a text field. The accepted answer can cause some problems if direct child is not a text field.

Comment: This works, but it does not show a scrollbar on the text field when it is scrolled, which can be confusing.

Comment: Another "gotcha" is if the user has their font size preferences to a large font, you might cause an overflow. The lines are based on font size no?

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer by Gunter is good enough if you don't have any style for the `TextField`. But if you have at least an underline / bottom border for the `TextField`, it will disappear when scroll up.

My recommendation is to calculating the lines with TextPainter, then apply the calculated number of lines to TextField. Here's the code, replace your current `TextField` with `LayoutBuilder` :

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, size){
      TextSpan text = new TextSpan(
        text: yourTextController.text,
        style: yourTextStyle,
      );

      TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
          text: text,
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      );
      tp.layout(maxWidth: size.maxWidth);

      int lines = (tp.size.height / tp.preferredLineHeight).ceil();
      int maxLines = 10;

      return TextField(
        controller: yourTextController,
        maxLines: lines < maxLines ? null : maxLines,
        style: yourTextStyle,
      );
    }
  )
```

Comment: Great implementation! I think this is the correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
TextField(
     minLines: 1,
     maxLines: 5,
     maxLengthEnforced: true,
),
```