# My Text Forms widget is not scrolling, same issue again.I tried adding SingleChildScrollView but it is not working

Tags: forms, flutter

In Flutter my Text Forms widget is not scrolling, same issue again.I tried adding SingleChildScrollView but  it is not working`.

Please fix my isue  I tried adding "  body: SingleChildScrollView( )  but the total forms page
is getting disappeared.

Following is my Widget code

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        ),

        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: isService ? TextInputType.streetAddress: TextInputType.text ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your SingleChildScrollView? Do you mean scroll within the TextFormField? If so, have you tried `maxLines` ? You can check its doc here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html

Comment: Also, see this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205333/flutter-textfield-that-auto-expands-when-text-is-entered-and-then-starts-scrolli/51205467#51205467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be two cases :

1. You have multiple textform field and you want to scroll between them
2. You have single text area in which you want to scroll

**for first one**,
Wrap your code inside a (column + SingleChildScrollView) or Listview and add as many textfield you want to add inside

**for second one**,
you can set max line for text form and it will behave like a textarea and to control height and width of it you can apply it under container and set height for it